# Why doesn't Paul Atreides give an order to stop the jihad?

Tags: dune

In *Dune Messiah*, why doesn't Paul just give orders to stop the Jihad? "Stop killing in my name," or punish those who do kill in his name?

Would the Fremen just disobey him? Is it not possible for him to order that many people? It isn't clear to me. I mean, he is Emperor.

Comment: Because he foresaw that the jihad was both inevitable and required?

Comment: Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YDzt-Y2zkg4

Comment: You missed the part in Messiah where Chani asked him exactly that and he explained why it would not work (may post an answer after finding it if no one else does first)?

Comment: @suchiuomizu - Ah, I forgot that quote. *“Chani, beloved,” he whispered, “do you know what I’d spend to end the Jihad—to separate myself from the damnable godhead the Qizarate forces onto me?” She trembled, “You have but to command it,” she said. “Oh, no. Even if I died now, my name would still lead them.* - Paul explicitly links his command to stop with his immediate death.

Comment: @Valorum, thanks yes that quote explains a lot. If he tried to stop the jihad, he'd be killed, and it would continue... maybe with increased fervor if the wrong people were blamed for his death.

Comment: @suchiuomizu - Are you going to post that into an answer? If not, I'll incorporate it into mine and credit you for the assist

Comment: “You have but to command it,” she said. | “Oh, no. Even if I died now, my name would still lead them." - Paul's answer isn't satisfying. Generally a war continues when a leader dies, and stops when a leader makes peace.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Fremen would disobey him or intentionally misunderstand him or kill him. It's all really much of a muchness and doesn't make a lot of difference in the grand scheme.

> They’re accustomed to seeing the future, Paul thought. In this place and time they’re blind…even as I am. And he sampled the time-winds, sensing the turmoil, the storm nexus that now focused on this moment place. Even the faint gaps were closed now. Here was the unborn jihad, he knew. Here was the race consciousness that he had known once as his own terrible purpose. Here was reason enough for a Kwisatz Haderach or a Lisan al-Gaib or even the halting schemes of the Bene Gesserit. The race of humans had felt its own dormancy, sensed itself grown stale and knew now only the need to experience turmoil in which the genes would mingle and the strong new mixtures survive. All humans were alive as an unconscious single organism in this moment, experiencing a kind of sexual heat that could override any barrier.
>
> **And Paul saw how futile were any efforts of his to change any smallest bit of this. He had thought to oppose the jihad within himself, but the jihad would be. His legions would rage out from Arrakis even without him. They needed only the legend he already had become. He had shown them the way, given them mastery even over the Guild which must have the spice to exist.**
>
> <sup><sub>Dune</sub></sup>